# Is there any nosql flat file database just as sqlite?

Tags: python, database, caching, sqlite, nosql

Short Question:
Is there any nosql flat-file database available as sqlite?

Explanation:
Flat file database can be opened in different processes to read, and keep one process to write. I think its perfect for read cache if there's no strict consistent needed. Say 1-2 secs write to the file or even memory block and the readers get updated data after that.

So I almost choose to use sqlite, as my python server read cache. But there's still one problem. I don't like to rewrite sqls again in another place and construct another copy of my data tables in sqlite just as the same as I did in PostgreSql which used as back-end database.

so is there any other choice?thanks!

Comment: There is UnQLite but I wonder why not write a NoSQL-kind document storage on top of SQLite. In some cases schemaless objects collection storage is convenient to have but isn't it good to still use a well-supported standard file format?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe `shelve`? It's basically a key-value store where you can store python objects. http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html

Or maybe you could just use the filesystem?

Comment: I would definitely go with shelve. I'm actually using load/dump from pickle in separate files for quick access, but shelve is a viable option.

Comment: ....I just forget it! Thanks so much for reminding me this great solution shipped with python!

Comment: Note that for concurrent reads/writes, `shelve` is not a viable alternative to sqlite.  From the python docs: "The shelve module does not support concurrent read/write access to shelved objects. (Multiple simultaneous read accesses are safe.) When a program has a shelf open for writing, no other program should have it open for reading or writing. Unix file locking can be used to solve this, but this differs across Unix versions and requires knowledge about the database implementation used."  sqlite, on the other hand, is ACID compliant on all supported OSes and does the locking work for you.

Comment: @chadrik 's comment should not go unnoticed... concurrent access is a fairly important point in the decision to migrate to shelve or not. If concurrent access is needed using the filesystem is a better option (as suggested in the answer).

Answer (score 9):

BerkeleyDB is a widely-used embedded database that's been around forever (it originally derived from the database library included in BSD, hence the name) and has excellent performance characteristics for many use cases (and caching is a frequently-used one), but it does have some significant limitations.

If you want to use it with Python, you'll probably want the [externally-maintained pybsddb/`bsddb3` library](http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm), not the [deprecated `bsddb` library](http://docs.python.org/library/bsddb.html) included in Python 2.x (and no longer in 3.x).

It's currently owned by Oracle, but available under an open-source license. Do take careful note of licensing terms -- current versions are GPLish (and GPL-compatible), so make sure that's compatible with what you plan to do.

More information:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BerkeleyDB
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleepycat_License
- http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/index.html

Comment: thanks so much for the recommendation! but after I saw what they did to mysql, I will step away from oracle. But I really considered bsdb as compare to sqlite. If they didn't sold it, I will definitely go with it. Thanks for the information you provide. It's valuable.

Comment: BerkelyDB is $15,000+ upwards in license fees even for simple iPhone apps. Maybe more if your name and startup looks more promising then mine.

Comment: @Lothar BDB is free software. You can develop more free software with it without any licensing fees.

Answer (score 0):

Something trivial but workable, if you are looking storage backed up key value data structure use pickled dictionary. Use cPickle for better performance if needed.

Comment: Use Sqlite or Firebird with just one table. 
Or the database component from the OpenLDAP project, which is ultra fast. 

http://symas.com/mdb/